# What is the difference between Timeline and Thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

The following two simple snippets do the same, print `"Hello, world"` each second. But what's the difference between them? When should I use a thread and when should I use Timeline. Does Timeline internally start a thread? if it doesn't, how the print gets executed each one second without blocking the main thread?

```java
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> System.out.println("Hello, world")));
timeline.setCycleCount(-1);
timeline.play();
```

```java
new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

And, In the second snippet, if I do `Thread.sleep(some_volatile_variable_of_main_thread_that_changes_overtime)`, How can I achieve the same functionality using `Timeline`.

Comment: From where did you get `Timeline`? Is it `javafx`? If yes then consider adding that tag to our question, because this class isn't part of standard `java` (at least from Java 11).

Comment: @Pshemo yes it's javafx. I've added the tag. This even opens a new question, why `Timeline` exists in javafx while it has NOTHING to do with UI

Comment: @Youssef13 The purpose of `Timeline` is for defining animations, which is why is uses a keyframe approach and which is why it is found in a UI library. It is not meant for general task scheduling.

Comment: You can probably throw Timer and TimerTask into the mix. I've never looked at Timeline but that looks like a variation of TimerTask rather than a proper thread.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde Thanks. but what would be bad if I used it for general task (not UI)

Comment: @ptyx What would be special for Timer and TimerTask compared to Thread? I think Timer uses a TimerThread internally.

Comment: @Youssef13 It's not so much that it would be bad per se, rather I am pushing back against the statement that it "has nothing to do with UI". A tool for scheduling tasks would look quite different from `Timeline`. E.g., frame rate, keyframes, playing, pausing, jumping, total duration, etc. - these are good control points for animation, but not what one would expect or want in a task scheduling library.

Comment: I vote for "it would be pretty bad to use `Timeline` for anything except UI animations."  All code has context, and `Timeline` is a domain object expressly for driving animations in the JavaFX framework.  Using it for anything else would not only likely be a feature mismatch for any other domain, it would also be hugely confusing to any maintainer that comes after you.

Comment: The major difference is that the code in the `Timeline` key frames is guaranteed to be executed on the FX Application Thread. Timelines also don’t start new threads, they are just updated during the existing FX Application Thread “pulse”

Comment: @Youssef13 nothing special about Timer/TimerThread - but they're relevant in a question that could be generalized as "if I want to do something every second or so, which Java API should I use"

Comment: If you are creating a `JavaFX` program use `Timeline`. If it's pure Java, use `Thread`. If you need to use Threading ideas in a JavaFX program, look into `Service` and/or `Task`.

Comment: Good resources: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm and https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Comment: One thing not mentioned by the answers: The timeline will automatically be shut down when the JavaFX platform shuts down; Your thread however will keep the app alive until you kill it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Thread` class is part of the standard Java API, and represents a background thread. When a `Thread` is started, the code in either its `Runnable`'s `run` method, or its own `run` method, executes essentially in parallel to other running threads. This allows code that may take a long time to run to execute without delaying other code that can be run "at the same time". The cost to the programmer of using this is that great care must be taken if data is shared between different threads, to ensure it is read in a consistent state in any single thread, and that data is "live": that is, that changes made to data in one thread are actually observed in other threads.

By contrast, `Timeline` is part of the JavaFX framework, and in particular part of its animation API. When a JavaFX application is started, a thread called the FX Application Thread starts running. This thread runs in a loop and is responsible for rendering the UI and processing user events (among other things). The UI rendering occurs on a "pulse", which is (in the current version) targeted to occur 60 times per second. Because of the data synchronization issues alluded to above, all changes to the UI ***must*** be made on the FX Application Thread. Additionally, code on the FX Application thread must not be long-running (so it cannot pause with a `sleep()`, or read large data sets over IO), because it would block the thread from rendering the UI.

A `Timeline` works by having a set of `KeyFrame`s, each of which specify a time (in the form of a `Duration`, measured since the timeline started) and an event handler and/or a `KeyValue`. On each pulse of the FX Application Thread, if a `Timeline` is running, the FX Application Thread loop will check if it is time to trigger any event handlers. For `KeyValue`s, if the value is interpolatable (e.g. is numeric, or implements `Interpolatable`, it's value will be calculated by computing the time elapsed as a proportion of the time for the next `KeyFrame`.

`Timeline`s are useful for simple animations (by, e.g., moving a node across a pane, by using `KeyValue`s that specify it's layout position or translation coordinates, or similar), and also for performing a discrete set of UI updates at specific times (e.g. showing and hiding images in a "memory" game).

Consequently:

- Code in event handlers for a `KeyFrame` attached to a `Timeline` may update the UI, since it is guaranteed to be executed on the FX Application Thread
- `KeyValue`s that are updated as part of a `KeyFrame` in a `Timeline` may be properties of UI elements that are displayed on the screen
- Code in event handlers for `KeyFrame`s must not block execution or perform long-running tasks
- Trying to use a `Timeline` in a non-JavaFX application (i.e. one where the JavaFX runtime has not been started) will fail, because there will be no JavaFX Application Thread to execute the updates.

Conversely:

- Code run on a background `Thread` ***must not*** update UI elements (or their properties). This is true both of JavaFX and Java Swing/AWT
- Code run on a background thread may block or execute long-running tasks

Note that the `java.util.Timer` and it's associated `TimerTask` (which are part of the standard Java API) execute on a background thread created internally by the `Timer`. This means that, although the API of `Timer` and `TimerTask` look somewhat similar to `Timeline`, they must obey the rules of background threads (must not update the UI, etc).

Answer (score 3):

In order to understand the difference, you need to think of two main questions:

- When we use a separate `Thread`, can we update JavaFX UI controls from the same thread?
- Given a `WritableValue`, how can we make a `Thread` change that value over time with a prespecified rate, start value, and end value?

From the `Timeline` documentation:

> A Timeline can be used to define a free form animation of any
>   WritableValue, e.g. all JavaFX Properties. A Timeline, defined by one
>   or more KeyFrames, processes individual KeyFrame sequentially, in the
>   order specified by KeyFrame.time. The animated properties, defined as
>   key values in KeyFrame.values, are interpolated to/from the targeted
>   key values at the specified time of the KeyFrame to Timeline's initial
>   position, depends on Timeline's direction.

Example: Bouncing a ball 14 times (each bounce takes 3 seconds)

```java
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3),
    new KeyValue(ball.layoutXProperty(), parentPane.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxX() - ball.getRadius())));
timeline.setCycleCount(14);
timeline.play();
```

In summary, `Timeline` was designed to support `Animation` by processing one or more `KeyFrame`s sequentially in the JavaFX thread.

- *When should I use a thread and when should I use Timeline?*

`Timeline` should be used for animations and updating writable UI values at a rate. `Thread` on the other hand should be used to run long background tasks (`ExecutorService` is always a better idea).

- *Does Timeline internally start a thread?*

No, `Timeline` doesn't start new threads, it uses the JavaFX thread.

- The last part is not exactly what a `Timeline` was designed for. If you have to change the duration, you need to reinitialize your `Timeline` or removing the old `KeyFrame` and adding a new one with the new duration.