# JavaFX, Java - number of active threads change listener

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, listener

in my program I have a status bar and there I indicate the number of active threads, using `Thread.activeCount()`, this is all fine but currently this is only updated when I click a button: I read again `Thread.activeCount()` and then update the number on the bar -- this is not very useful since I have to request "manually" to update the number.

```
@FXML
public void btnShowThreads() {
    btnShowThreads.setText(String.valueOf(Thread.activeCount()));
}
```

What I need to do is have this on a listener, and I couldn't find a way to do so. I am trying to avoid to use a timer, e.g. to run every 0.5 seconds to update the number -- as threads could be the same number for long periods of time.

How can this be achieved? How can I listen to `Thread.activeCount()` changes?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: You can't, at least not purely with Java. A timer (or better, an animation) that runs every half second should be fine. But also keep in mind that method is not completely reliable, as noted in [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#activeCount()).

Comment: If you're controlling the creation and execution of all the threads/background tasks, you can create an `Executor` that tracks how many are running and submit them to that executor. That's probably a nicer solution than continually polling `Thread.activeCount()` if you are operating in that context; it's slightly different to the way you've posed the question though.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, Java doesn't offer such an option to listen to thread changes. As an alternative, you can use a `Timeline`:

```java
// a Timeline with a KeyFrame that runs for 1 second and updates the value when the cycle finishes
Timeline updater = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), event -> {
    activeThreadsLabel.setText("Threads: " + Thread.activeCount());
    event.consume();
}));
updater.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE); // run indefinitly
updater.play(); // start
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can add a "listener" of sorts.. it could be possible. However what about updating certain aspects of your UI on a set interval within a dedicated thread? This is the same approach you'd take to adding a stopwatch or something.

Something like...

```
// pesudo code

Thread uiUpdated = () -> {
    while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
        // Update on FX thread - other will cause error
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            // Update your UI here
            myNode.setText("Idk some text here");
        });
        
         // Only update the UI every 1s
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored){ }
    }
};
```

You can start it with start() and stop it with interrupt()
You can even pause and resume a thread with wait() and notify()
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: You can read this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489649/what-is-the-difference-between-timeline-and-thread-in-java) post on Timelines and Threads.

Comment: Yes I did! Very helpful!